# SDL_Delay halts rendering when used with Emscripten?

Tags: c, animation, sdl-2, emscripten

I have an SDL2 game written in C which utilizes animations heavily. Animations are implemented as following (approx.) :

```
drawObject(x,y);
SDL_Delay(n);
clearScreen();
drawObject(x+1,y);
```

This code is expected to draw a sprite in one place, then in n seconds move it forward. It works as expected when compiled with gcc and run as an executable.

However, the same code compiled into JavaScript using Emscripten produces odd results. The program waits for n seconds with black screen and then draws object on (x+1,y), almost as if the first 3 lines do not exist.

Why is this happening in JavaScript?
And, more importantly, how do I implement animations that would work when compiled into JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, developers used precisely timed delays to draw stuff in games, synchronizing with the display and all kinds of tricks. However, nowadays, that it is not how things are done.

What you are supposed to do is to clear the backbuffer (e.g. [`SDL_RenderClear`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear) for the included 2D renderer), render your latest state available and then present (e.g. [`SDL_RenderPresent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent)).

[`SDL_Delay()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay) is a just a portable sleep function, which means it makes the entire thread go to sleep. The JS animation loop is running independently, and somehow if your "C thread" is sleeping it simply draws a black screen, for whatever reason. That reason can be understood checking out the Emscripten source code that maps the SDL calls to JS/canvas/WebGL calls, but those details could change any time.

In other words, don't do that!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The remaining question is : how do I time the re-rendering of the state? If I need something on the screen for n seconds, what other alternatives there are to sleep(n)? The only ones I can come up with is littering the game loop with ifs and counting how much times the given picture was rendered, but that seems to be an ugly solution

Comment: @FlappyBoy123 Either you use animations that last a given number of fixed ticks, or you calculate it based on the current time.